# Can I use a notarized copy's photocopy? In British common law?

Tags: notaries

Suppose, I have a certificate from a university of which I made a copy and got it notarized by a notary public.

Can I use the photocopy of that notarized copy with a visa application? Would the visa officer consider that as a valid document?

N.B. I want to do that in order to avoid notarizing those copies times and again.

Comment: Visa officer of what embassy?

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic.  As far as I know, it would be at the discretion of the visa officers to decide, either as a matter of policy or case-by-case, what documents are needed for any given application, and in particular whether they should be notarized.  I don't think it's specified in law.  If you want practical advice on visa applications, Travel.SE is a better place to ask.

Comment: Notaries may or may not be allowed to make certified copies of an education document. Some notaries are aware that sometimes this process has been abused, so some notaries may decline even if they're allowed. If a notary will do it at all, the notary might agree to a quantity discount, and notarize, say, 10 copies at once for less than what he/she would charge for 10 copies on 10 separate occasions.

Comment: U.S. evidence law would generally allow introduction of a photocopy of a notarized document to be introduced absent of bona fide and articulated reason why a photocopy is insufficient. I don't know what British evidence rules provide and any embassy for a country may follow that country's rules.